# SVN-Repository on local filesystem in Subclipse with weird preceding path

Tags: windows, eclipse, svn, path, subclipse

I have a SVN-Repository on my Win7-PC Harddrive. I am able to use it with TortoiseSVN from Explorer-Contextmenu as intended without having any kind of SVN-Server running locally.

I tried to use my Repository from within Eclipse via Subclipse. I created a folder share on my Repository and tried variuos URLs like these:

```
file:///\\OMPHALOSKOPIE\Repository
```

The errormessage I am receiving is the following:

```
svn: 'C:\Users\Henno\Software\springsource\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\file:\OMPHALOSKOPIE\Repository' does not exist
```

Basically it doesn't matter what my URL looks like, the path to my Eclipse-copy always shows up in front of it. Adding /../../ or similar does not work. Writing anything in front of "file:" will not qualify as a URL. Other protocols like "svn:" and "https:" do not have the weird path-attachment, I am perfectly able to browse random google-code-repositorys from Eclipse for instance.

Is there a hidden config-file that has some root-folder-prefix set to my install-path? I could find anything alike.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

I used the wrong Subclipse Update-site and therefore had the wrong Subclipse-Version installed.

Instead of:

```
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update
```

which will just install v1.0 not the newest version. Newest is currently 1.8, its obtainable over

```
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x
```

File-Entries will work now without any trouble... thanks to everybody who put effort into my problem!

Comment: thx helped me as well right now as older tutorials often have the `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update` in it...